# I upgraded my app from xamarin to maui and now I can't publish it in the MS store

Tags: maui, maui-windows, microsoft-store

I get this error: A previous submission for this app was released with a Windows 10/11 .msixbundle or .appxbundle. Subsequent submissions must continue to contain a Windows 10/11 .msixbundle or .appxbundle.

Maui apps publish as MSIX and my xamarin app publish as appxbundle. I would imagine, there has to be a work around for this.  We are forced to upgrade our apps to Maui so there has to be a way to upgrade them in the store.

I tried MS Store support, but I get the runaround.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you successfully [generate the MSIX bundle package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/bundle-msix-packages)?